# How to output a bmp file using verilog?

Tags: verilog, binaryfiles

I was asked to using the data in a bmp file as the simulation input for a verilog module and write the simulation output to a new bmp file, so that they can compare the two different bmp file to check the correction of verilog module.
I succeeded in read, but met some problems in writing.

`module testsub1;
integer fout;
initial 
    begin
        fout=$fopen("C:/Users/gyz/Pictures/testout1.bmp","wb");
        $fwrite(fout,"%u",8'h42);
        $fclose(fout);
    end
endmodule`

The output is supposed to be 8'h42. But the real output is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdxFB.png)

Needless zero occur. I guess it is because verilog write row binary at least 16n bit at a time, n >=1. So I change the sixth line into `$fwrite(fout,"%u",24'h424d5f);`,the result becomes 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raA3X.png)
There is still a redundant zero. How can I make the program just output 8 bits each time.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033790/verilog-fwrite-output-bytes By the way: I just tried "%u" in Vivado 2017.2 which gives a system fatal error.

Comment: Thanks. The answer under that question do solve my problems. Though I still feel confused that %c or %C means display in ASCII character format in IEEE standard for verilog. How can it output binary file? But it do works, thank you again for your help.

Comment: "%c" outputs a 8-bit value. Mostly it is used to output a printable character and that it can be any 8-bit value is often forgotten in the many text that explains the various output % formats. Also if you look at the printf explanations in C.

Answer (score 0):

[verilog fwrite output bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033790/verilog-fwrite-output-bytes)

Under this question, dave_59's solution works well.

> You can use %c to write out a single byte. You can use a bit-stream cast to convert your data into an array of bytes, then do foreach(array_of_bytes[i]) `$fwrite(fd,"%c",array_of_bytes[i])`;
>
> If you have a large amount of data, you may want to optimize this by writing out the multiple of 4-bytes with `%u`, and the remaining bytes with `%c`.